How to exclude Docker processes from Process Snapshot output?
I want to list all processes running at the server except all processes running in Docker containers.
So, for example I have Redis and Nginx at the server and MySQL and Apache running in Docker containers.
I want to get only on-server processes: redis, nginx, docker.
Is it possible to exclude child docker processes from ps output not using grep?

The only way of working I can use is
ps waxfu --no-headers | grep -v "\\_" | grep "[p]rocessname"
But it looks like an ugly kludge, no more. I want to know if there's ps instrument or something else
